# SQL sum across columns by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with lots of columns, some of them with names beginning with "EQ". For an individual row, I'd like to sum all the values in the columns that start with "EQ", but not the other values. I know I can do it like this:

```
select EQ_DOMESTIC + EQ_INTL + EQ_OTHER from myTable where id=1
```

However, I have lots of columns, and I was wondering if I can do it systematically, without typing in the name of each column. Would I have to get the column names from the system tables in another query?

**Follow up question:** Some of the values are nulls, which makes the sum NULL. Is there any way to avoid writing out ISNULL(column,0) for the sum?

Comment: can't think of one and you need to write out isnull(columnname, 0) for each column not just for the contatentated sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
   + COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ', 0)'
FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
  AND name LIKE 'EQ[_]%';

SELECT @sql += N',' + QUOTENAME(name)
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
  AND name NOT LIKE 'EQ[_]%';

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT [EQ_SUM] = 0' + @sql
  + ' FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE id = 1;';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```